# i am transferring control to a function written in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function Edit() {
    var mode = 2; // 2 For Edit      
    var Fid = 0;
    var viewName = 'MemberEditor';
    var actionURL = '@Url.Action("setViewMode", "Member")';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            Mode: mode,
            lFeatureId: Fid,
            ViewName: viewName
        },
        url: actionURL,
        success: function (result) {
            setViewMode(result);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the function where in i am calling setViewMode(result).
but somehow it is sot being called properly..

```
function setViewMode(data) {
    for (keyVar in data) {
        if (keyVar.search("Btn") != -1) {
            jQuery('#' + keyVar).attr("disabled", data[keyVar]);
        } else {
            jQuery('#' + keyVar).prop("readonly", data[keyVar]);
        }
    }
}
```

The control isn't getting transferred to the loop. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try debugging the ajax call, see if it fires the success function.

Comment: it is firing the function.. it is not going into the loop.. @Skatch

Comment: Have you checked what data is being returned?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` and see what you get. (By the way, you can set `success: setViewData` - there's no need for the anonymous function when all it does is pass its argument through to `setViewData()`.)

Comment: did you debug the result variable?

Comment: use either `.attr()` or `.prop()` in the `if/else` statements. Inface you should use `.prop()` for both because both of them are properties.

Comment: debugging result just shows object Object.. the data is being passed but the function i need is not happening correctly

Comment: none of this is working.. i tried everything..! :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting back a JSON string. Use .$parseJSON(data) to get the contents stored.

Comment: You mean a JSON **string**

Comment: @Anand where exactly do you want me to do the change?

Comment: success: function (result) {
               var data=$.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(data);  //use this to debug  
            setViewMode(data);
        }